# iOS app behaves differently with debug vs release scheme

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, background-process, dispatch-async

In my app I have three internet operations that run at once.  They don't depend on each other so I run each of them in a background thread.  They each need to be complete though before my app can move on to the completion handler.

The method that starts each of the three receives as a parameter, block code that functions as a completion handler.  This method also has a local variable called internetOperationsRemaining that I set equal to 3 before I start each of the three internet operations.

When each of the internet operations is complete I decrement internetOperationsRemaining on the main thread.  This results in internetOperationsRemaining == 0 when they are all complete.

To listen for this condition I run a tight loop on another background thread that simply loops on itself waiting for internetOperationsRemaining to equal 0.  Once that happens I call the completion handler that was passed in as a parameter as previously described.

```
    //Spawn a background thread and loop in it until
    //allInternetOperationComplete == true.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        while(internetOperationsRemaining > 0)
        {
            //Just spins in here on a background thread waiting 
            //on the internet to finish.
        }

        //Now that internetOperationsRemaining == 0, kill the NSURL session 
        //and call the completion handler on the main thread.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
            completionHandler();   
        });
  });
```

The strange behavior that I am seeing is that the app runs perfectly if I have debug set in the scheme, and it doesn't if I have release selected.  It simply never breaks out of the while loop.

If I insert some trivial code in the while loop to slow things down just a little it works fine in both debug and release.

```
    while(internetOperationsRemaining > 0)
    {
        //Just spins in here on a background thread waiting 
        //on the internet to finish.
        int i=0;
        ++i;
    }
```

I am at a loss to explain this behavior.  The tight loop is on a background thread so the app remains responsive to user input as would be expected.  I realize that the release scheme introduces optimizations, but I am surprised it actually changed the apps behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without running code to check, I would think that what is going on is some sort of compiler optimisation which only occurs in Release code.

I think the real problem though is more about design. Using counters and having a thread spinning is not great. I would suggest looking into using NSOperations. You can setup hierarchies of operations so that your completion operation is dependant on the other three. Go read up on using operations, concurrent queues and dependencies and you will get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I didn't like the tight loop spinning either, but wasn't aware of NSOperation.  It took about 5 minutes of reading to realize this provides exactly what I was trying to do.  I will rewrite this section of code tomorrow using your suggestion, and if if it cures the problem (which I suspect it will) I will certainly select your response as the answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: The method calls that I am waiting on to complete each call NSURLSession methods that are themselves asynchronous with their own completion handlers.  Simply putting these methods in an NSOperations queue leaves me with my original problem.  The NSURLSession methods are called, the NSBlockOperation finishes and this all happens before the NSURLSession methods have completed.  I am looking into a custom subclass of NSOperation to see if I can get it to work that way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are running an operation that calls a async method. Therefore the operation is ending before the method. One technique I've used in the past to deal with this is to lock the current thread until second thread finishes. Then resume the current thread. Look at the Threading Programming Guide for details and the section on locks. It's been a while, but I think a NSConditionalLock may be what you are looking for.

Comment: So NSOperation and NSBlockOperation turned out to be the solution.  I just needed to subclass NSOperation and do all my NSURLSession work in there.  Once the NSURLSession completion handler is called,  it in turn calls the NSOperation completeOperation method.  Then it is a very simple matter to add dependencies so that the methods are all complete before I move on.